# Angular service not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm building an application with Angular(client side) and Node (server side). I'm using some API's in Angular but am stuck with retrieving data from a particular API. Can anybody help?

This is my API's response JSON:

```
{
    "devices": [
        {
            "name": "led1",
            "driver": "Led",
            "connection": "driver",
            "commands": [
                "is_on",
                "turn_on",
                "turn_off",
                "toggle",
                "brightness",
                "current_brightness"
            ],
            "details": {
                "pin": 12
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "led2",
            "driver": "Led",
            "connection": "driver",
            "commands": [
                "is_on",
                "turn_on",
                "turn_off",
                "toggle",
                "brightness",
                "current_brightness"
            ],
            "details": {
                "pin": 13
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "sensor",
            "driver": "AnalogSensor",
            "connection": "driver",
            "commands": [
                "analog_read"
            ],
            "details": {
                "pin": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my angular service:

```
angular.module('robots.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Robots', function($resource) {
  return $resource(
      'http://dionaudio.local:8090/api/robots/Dionaudio.local/devices/:devices',
      { //method: 'robots', q: 'robots'
      }, // Query parameters
      {'query': { method: 'GET' }}
);
});
```

Controller and app.js

```
.controller('RobotsCtrl', function($scope, Robots) {
  $scope.robots = Robots.query();
});

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider

      .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
      })

      .state('app.robots', {
        url: "/robots",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/robots.html",
            controller: 'RobotsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('app.deviceinfo', {
        url: "/deviceinfo",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/deviceinfo.html",
            controller: 'DeviceinfoCtrl'
          }
        }
      });

      // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/deviceinfo');
    });
```

And finally my template:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="robot in robots" href="">{{robot.name}}</ion-item>
```

I am only getting one result and no name output. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: No, there is no controller.

Comment: Name is an attribute of the JSON objects in the devices array. You want `{{robots.devices.name}}`.

Comment: You should have a controller. Please show the code for that.

Comment: Sorry, i was editing additional info :-) It's there now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to point to the array in your json

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="robot in robots.devices" href="">{{robot.name}}</ion-item>
```

And for your question below, you'll need something like

```
  .state('app.robots', {
    url: "/robots/:robotName",
    views: {...
```

Comment: Hope i am not over asking, but Angular is quite difficult. Now i can't get the detail partial to work. This is my controller:

`code

    .controller('RobotCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Robot) {
      $scope.robot = Robot.get({robotName: $stateParams.robotName});
    });
`

Comment: Thanks again mate! I did not help unfortunately, i am now showing details in the main list...